# P-value and Bayesian Inference

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, p-value

I know the [technical definition of a p-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value), but that definition is at face value useless.  I want to know how to adjust my beliefs given the evidence presented.

Does p-value relate to any of the terms in Bayesian inference?

$P(H|E) = \frac{P(E|H)P(H)}{P(E)}$

I had previously thought that p-value could corresponded to the P(E|H) term, but not sure if that's true.

EDIT:  H is hypothesis, E is evidence

Comment: Is H hypothesis and E evidence?

Comment: In a sense the $p$ value is $$\sum\limits_{\substack{E \text { as or more }\\ \text{extreme than} \\ \text{observed}}} \mathbb P(E \mid H_0)$$ making the suitable transformation to an integral if necessary, where $H_0$ is the null hypothesis.  This is not a Bayesian approach

Comment: How to construct/write a $H_0$ in Bayesian statistics?

Comment: @Henry What if I reframe E as "having something observed as or more extreme than observed"

Comment: @Jack If $E$ is what is observed or anything as extreme or more extreme as observed then the $p$ value is $\mathbb P(E \mid H_0)$